# Tableau: I need to get the difference in days between two dates. Datediff is giving incorrect result, why?

Tags: tableau-api

I am using DATEDIFF as

```
DATEDIFF('day', #2016-12-24#, #2016-12-22#)
```

I am getting the result as -1468. If I interchange the dates, I am getting 1468
While the difference is just 2 days.

If I use `DATEDIFF('day', #2016-12-24#, TODAY())` I am getting 8808. why?
Any help is greatly appreciated in getting the dates difference properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weird problem with Tableau. Here is the solution. https://community.tableau.com/thread/122324

Tableau automatically uses SUM() when we drag this field into rows/columns. 
We need to use non-additive aggregation like MIN() MAX() AVG() or MEDIAN().

Thanks Shawn, for your answer in the Tableau Community.

Answer (score 0):

Format for DATEDIFF Function: DATEDIFF(date_part, [Start Time], [End Time]. It is showing -1468 because you're using end time first and start time later. Make sure your start and end times are in string format.